# Show folder names in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio to show the foldernames of files:

- In the top-tabs in the code-window.
- In the selection popup at CTRL-TAB.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built in feature for this and Microsoft [refuse to bother](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2671548-give-option-to-show-parent-folder-name-in-tabs) to add it (even though it was added to VS Code lately).
If you're rich, TabsStudio [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555858/1057791) to have this ability for the tabs.

If you want some alternative solution you could use one of those plugins:

FilePathOnFooter - 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.FilePathOnFooter

Customize Visual Studio Window Title - 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle